# Angular Frontend with JAX-RS backend

Tags: iis, glassfish, angularjs, jax-rs, cors

I have a RESTful Java backend which I made using Jersey, a JAX-RS implementation. This backend is running on a glassfish server on port 8084. I've also made some HTML5/JS/AJAX pages which display the data so I know my REST implementation is working.

I'm trying to develop an HTML5 / JS frontend for this application using the Angular.js framework but I'm experiencing some trouble. I have managed to develop some small webapps in angular which I'm running on Microsoft's IIS on port 80.

Unfortunately, there appears to be a problem with the communication between the two applications. Since I'm new to Angular, I'm unsure if I made a mistake in my frontend code, or if I'm experiencing CORS problems. I already tried running the backend on a Tomcat 7 with the CORS filter but that didn't solve anything.

My angular code looks like this:

**services.js**

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('ServiceModule', ['ngResource']);
serviceModule.factory('NodeService', function($resource) {
var NodeService = $resource('http://localhost:port/HtmlJerseyJava/service/node/get/3',{},
    {
        'get' : { method: 'GET',params:{port:':8084'}}
    }
)
return NodeService;
```

});

**controllers.js**

```
function NodeDetailCtrl($scope, NodeService){
    var node3 = NodeService.get();
    $scope.data = JSON.stringify(node3) ;
}
```

I hardcoded the ID 3 for now, because I also need to figure out how I can pass the value of an input field from the view to the controller and then to the service. Eventually, the 3 in the service url would be replaced by a variable :nodeId

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Pieter. 

Have you already checked what kind of communication takes place? You can use Firebug or Google Chrome Developer Tools for that. These tools allow you to check, which requests are sent from the client to the server and what the response is. I guess you ran into a CORS problem. But checking the network traffic (as described above) could prove that guess.

Greets Marc

Comment: It appears my Angular frontend never actually sends a request to my REST backend.

With the HTML AJAX files, I can clearly see a GET request being sent to the REST URL. 

With my Angular application, the only request that appears to be sent is the one that requests the HTML page on which the JSON data should have been displayed.

Comment: Ok, so now I've managed to alter my code so that I get a 403 forbidden error. Does this mean I'm struggling with CORS then?

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a CORS error. You can re-verify that by checking network traffic. There should be a OPTIONAL request (instead of GET).

Comment: I managed to enable CORS on my backend on the glassfish server, eliminating the 403 error. I can retrieve the data via JS/AJAX hosted on IIS, thus there should no longer be a CORS issue. Unfortunately, it's still not working via the Angular resource component. It appears there was both a CORS problem and an Angular coding error. Any idea perhaps on the coding error?

Comment: I've just posted a possible answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. There were several steps to fix this problem:

1. Add a CORS filter to the Jersey servlet on Glassfish.
2. Upgrade the Angular version to 1.1.x (currently still unstable)
3. Set a custom header in your resource.
4. Enjoy a working application.

Big thanks Marcbaur for helping me out here.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following simplified code:

app.js (for test purposes I suggest you to put functions in one js file)

```
var serviceModule = angular.module('ServiceModule', ['ngResource']);
serviceModule.factory('Node', function($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:port/HtmlJerseyJava/service/node/get/3',{port:':8084'},
    {
        get {method:'GET'}
    });
});

serviceModule.controller('NodeDetailCtrl', function($scope, Node){
    $scope.data = Node.get();
}
```

It would be interesting to now what JSON data your client gets from the REST call.

Greets Marc

Comment: This is the json object that is returned by the REST API:  {"id":3,"name":"ghi6814","properties":{}}. There is also an HTTP header which indicates whether the request succeeded. I tried it this way, and it also failed. The request still doesn't show up in firebug either. I also tried with $http but with the same result.

Comment: Hey Peter. So you get some json data as result? Then the requestbseems to work?! Have you switched to the "Net"-Panel in Firebug and enabled it before sending the request again?

Comment: I can retrieve the JSON data with a simple AJAX request on an HTML page. This HTML page resides on the Web Server, and connects succesfully to the Application Server so I'd expect that the CORS problem is solved.

I changed to the NET panel in firebug, and I can see the request there. But there is a difference. In stead of GET 3, it says OPTIONS 3. The URL is correct and it returns Status 200. However in the request header, the return type is wrong. It doesn't say application/JSON, and I think that's the reason why the answer is empty

Comment: The request header Accept is text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml and it should be application/json. The response type is application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml but I'm expecting the response type is wrong because the request sends wrong headers.

Comment: Mmh okay. normally you should have a OPTIONS request and after that a GET request. To get application/json as return type you have to add the corresponding annotation

@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })

to the method in your java REST resource class.